# How to write javaScript function for this?

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox and i write javascript function that if it is blank then it will generate alertbox .
but i press space in that textbox then it doesnot generate alertbox.

so i want that if i give space then it also generate alertbox, for this what to do?

I used this function:

```
function Trim(objValue) {
    var lRegExp = /^\s+/;
    var rRegExp = /\s+$/;
    objValue = objValue.replace(lRegExp, ''); //Perform LTRim
    objValue = objValue.replace(rRegExp, ''); //perform RTrim
    return objValue;
}
function ValidateTextBoxIncome() {
    var txtEnterItems = document.getElementById("txtEnterItems");
 if (Trim(txtEnterItems) == '') {
        alert("Cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }
}
```

where is the error? please suggest me.

Comment: I assume you're actually adding ValidateTextBoxIncome as an event handler on some event. Is that correct, or is this all the JavaScript you have?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the DOM object to your function, but intended to pass the value of that textbox. Replace this line:

```
if (Trim(txtEnterItems) == '') {
```

by:

```
if (Trim(txtEnterItems.value) == '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var txtEnterItems = document.getElementById("txtEnterItems");
```

with

```
var txtEnterItems = document.getElementById("txtEnterItems").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function ValidateTextBoxIncome() {
    var txtEnterItems = document.getElementById("txtEnterItems");
    if (Trim(txtEnterItems.value).length == 0) {
        alert("Cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never saw a mention of a framework like jQuery, so I expect pure Javascript. `String.length` is not a function.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: You are right. length is not a function but a property on the string object. I have changed the code accordingly.